# Capybara assert dropdown having a desired value selected not working

Tags: capybara, html-select

```
$ruby --version
ruby 1.9.3dev (2011-09-23 revision 33323) [i686-linux]

gem 'rails', '3.2.9'

group :test do
  gem 'cucumber-rails', require: false
  gem 'capybara', '~> 2.0.3'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'factory_girl'
  gem "ffaker"
  gem "capybara-firebug", "~> 1.3.0"
  gem 'ruby-debug19'
end
```

In one of my Cucumber Step I am trying to assert that a drop-down element
(<select> tag) has a particular option selected using Capybara API
with the following code.

```
  within('#myForm') do
    page.has_select?("#event_type", selected: @event_type).should be_true
  end
```

However I am getting this error:

```
   expected: true value
   got: false (RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError)
```

I inspected the DOM using **@firebug** tag of (capybara-firebug) on my scenario
and found that the desired option (held by @event_type) is getting selected
in the drop-down however in the DOM the "selected" attribute is not getting
added to the select tag which I guess is causing the expectation to fail.

I found a similar reference here: https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/issues/171
which mentions about the commit having the fix but I guess the commit is not
merged to the capybara version I am using.I trying digging in the source code
and found that the fixes mentioned at https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/issues/171
are not present in the Capybara's codebase.

Can any body please let me know how to assert that a select tag has a
particular option selected?

Note: When using capybara in my Gem file without any version:

```
gem 'capybara'
```

Capybara Version 2.1.0 is initiated to be installed however it fails with error:

```
capybara requires Ruby version >= 1.9.3
```

though I have the required ruby version.

Following is the output of

```
  $ rvm info
  ruby-1.9.3-rc1:

system:
  uname:       "Linux jigneshgohel-Inspiron-N5110 3.2.0-40-generic-pae #64-Ubuntu SMP Mon Mar 25 21:44:41 UTC 2013 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux"
  bash:        "/bin/bash => GNU bash, version 4.2.24(1)-release (i686-pc-linux-gnu)"
  zsh:         " => not installed"

rvm:
  version:      "rvm 1.13.4 (stable) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]"
  updated:      "11 months 4 days 14 hours 20 minutes 18 seconds ago"

ruby:
  interpreter:  "ruby"
  version:      "1.9.3dev"
  date:         "2011-09-23"
  platform:     "i686-linux"
  patchlevel:   "2011-09-23 revision 33323"
  full_version: "ruby 1.9.3dev (2011-09-23 revision 33323) [i686-linux]"

homes:
  gem:          "/home/jigneshgohel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-rc1"
  ruby:         "/home/jigneshgohel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-rc1"

binaries:
  ruby:         "/home/jigneshgohel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-rc1/bin/ruby"
  irb:          "/home/jigneshgohel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-rc1/bin/irb"
  gem:          "/home/jigneshgohel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-rc1/bin/gem"
  rake:         "/home/jigneshgohel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-rc1/bin/rake"

environment:
  PATH:         "/home/jigneshgohel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-rc1/bin:/home/jigneshgohel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-rc1@global/bin:/home/jigneshgohel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-rc1/bin:/home/jigneshgohel/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/heroku/bin:/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/media/work/Environment/Languages/Java/jdk1.7.0_04/bin:/media/work/Environment/BuildTools/apache-maven-3.0.4/bin:/media/work/Environment/BuildTools/apache-ant-1.8.3/bin"
  GEM_HOME:     "/home/jigneshgohel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-rc1"
  GEM_PATH:     "/home/jigneshgohel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-rc1:/home/jigneshgohel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-rc1@global"
  MY_RUBY_HOME: "/home/jigneshgohel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-rc1"
  IRBRC:        "/home/jigneshgohel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-rc1/.irbrc"
  RUBYOPT:      ""
  gemset:       "
```

Following is the output of:

```
  $rvm list
  rvm rubies

  =* ruby-1.9.3-rc1 [ i686 ]

  # => - current
  # =* - current && default
  #  * - default
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't use cucumber, but in you example

```
within('#myForm') do
  page.has_select?("#event_type", selected: @event_type).should be_true
end
```

it depends on your dom, but you don't have to use '#' in the id selector here,
and 'selected:' should be the text in the option, not the value.

so it should be (assuming @event_type is what you are displaying for the text)

```
within('#myForm') do
  page.has_select?("event_type", selected: @event_type).should be_true
end
```

or i'd prefer

```
page.should have_select('event_type', selected: @event_type)
```